# Display random questions with no delay

Tags: java, android

How I would like the questions to be like;

When first question is shown, users don't enter the answer. Instead, user has to memorize the answer and with no delay, 2nd question is shown together with the first question still being shown. After every 2 questions, user can only enter the answer for both questions at the same time. However, I'm not sure how to show it in terms of codes. Also, is it possible to go the next question without having to click on the enter button? if it's possible, how do I that?

I want this to happen for the next subsequent questions. I'm still a beginner thus I need some help. I hope I am clear if not, do let me know.

These are my codes;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.enter) {
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        if(firstQuestion == true)
        {
            buttonCounter = 1;
            firstQuestion = false;
            replayBtn.setEnabled(true);
            chooseQuestion();
        } else if (!answerContent.endsWith("?")) {
            int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
            int exScore = getScore();
            if (enteredAnswer == answer){
                buttonCounter = 1;
                replayBtn.setEnabled(true);
                scoreTxt.setText("Score: " + (exScore + 1));
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                setHighScore();
                buttonCounter = 1;
                replayBtn.setEnabled(true);
                if (exScore == 0) {
                    scoreTxt.setText("Score:0");
                } else {
                    scoreTxt.setText("Score: " + (exScore - 1));
                }
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            chooseQuestion();
        }
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {

        if (buttonCounter == 1) {
            replayBtn.setEnabled(false);
            Log.d("ins", "called");
        }
        buttonCounter = 0;

        final int DELAY_MS = 1000;



        MediaPlayer firstNum = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                numberAudioList[operand1]);

        firstNum.start();
        pauseTimer = true;
        firstNum.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer firstNum) {
                firstNum.stop();
                firstNum.reset();
                firstNum.release();

                pauseTimer = false;

            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaPlayer operatorAudio = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                operatorAudioList[operator]);

        operatorAudio.start();
        pauseTimer = true;
        operatorAudio.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer operatorAudio) {
                operatorAudio.stop();
                operatorAudio.reset();
                operatorAudio.release();

                pauseTimer = false;
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaPlayer secondNum = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                numberAudioList[operand2]);

        secondNum.start();
        pauseTimer = true;
        secondNum.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer secondNum) {
                secondNum.stop();
                secondNum.reset();
                secondNum.release();

                pauseTimer = false;
            }
        });

        if (leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal == 0) {
            if (countDownTimer != null) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }
            setTimer(originalTimerTimeInMilliSeconds);
        } else {
            if (countDownTimer != null) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();

            }
            setTimer(leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal);
        }

        startTimer();

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.clear) {

        cancel = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cancel);
        cancel.start();
        cancel.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer cancel) {
                cancel.stop();
                cancel.reset();
                cancel.release();
            }
        });

        answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    } else {
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        if (answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
            answerTxt.setText("= " + enteredNum);
        else
            answerTxt.append("" + enteredNum);

        MediaPlayer num = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                numberAudioList[enteredNum]);
        num.start();
        num.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer num) {
                num.stop();
                num.reset();
                num.release();

            }
        });

    }
}

private void setTimer(long timeLeft) {

    totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = timeLeft;

    timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 20 * 1000;
}

private void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

            if (pauseTimer == true) {
                leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal = leftTimeInMilliseconds;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            } else {

                leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal = leftTimeInMilliseconds;

                if (leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds) {
                    textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.style.blinkText);

                    if (blink) {
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    blink = !blink;
                }

                textViewShowTime.setText(String
                        .format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                        + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("check", "check if enter onFinish() method");
            setResults();
            saveScore();
            Log.i("check", "check if passes through");
        }
    }.start();
}

private int getScore() {
    String scoreStr = scoreTxt.getText().toString();
    return Integer
            .parseInt(scoreStr.substring(scoreStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
}

private void chooseQuestion() {
    answerTxt.setText("= ?"); //first reset the answer Text View
    operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);

    if (operator == 0) {
        do {
            operand1 = getOperand1();
            operand2 = getOperand2();
            answer = getAnswer();
        } while ((answer > 20));

        answer = operand1 + operand2;
    } else if (operator == 1) {
        do {
            operand1 = getOperand1();
            operand2 = getOperand2();
            answer = getAnswer();
        } while ((operand2 > operand1) || answer > 20);

        answer = operand1 - operand2;
    } else if (operator == 2) {

        do {
            operand1 = getOperand1();
            operand2 = getOperand2();
            answer = getAnswer();
        } while (operand1 > 12 || operand2 > 12 || (answer > 20));
        answer = operand1 * operand2;
    } else if (operator == 3) {
        do {
            operand1 = getOperand1();
            operand2 = getOperand2();
            answer = getAnswer();
        } while (((((double) operand1 / (double) operand2) % 1 > 0)
                || answer > 20 || (operand1 == operand2) || (operand1 == 0) || (operand2 == 0)));
        answer = operand1 / operand2;
    }

    final int DELAY_MS = 1000;

    // moved to onClick()



    MediaPlayer firstNum = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            numberAudioList[operand1]);

    pauseTimer = true;
    firstNum.start();
    firstNum.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer firstNum) {
            firstNum.stop();
            firstNum.reset();
            firstNum.release();
            pauseTimer = false;
        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaPlayer operatorAudio = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            operatorAudioList[operator]);

    pauseTimer = true;
    operatorAudio.start();
    operatorAudio.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer operatorAudio) {
            operatorAudio.stop();
            operatorAudio.reset();
            operatorAudio.release();
            pauseTimer = false;
        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaPlayer secondNum = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            numberAudioList[operand2]);

    pauseTimer = true;
    secondNum.start();
    secondNum.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer secondNum) {
            secondNum.stop();
            secondNum.reset();
            secondNum.release();
            pauseTimer = false;
        }
    });

    int i = getScore();
    if (i < 5) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            question.setText(operand1 + " " + operators[operator] + " "
                    + operand2); //display the question to the user
        }
    } else {
        question.setText("Qns" + (i + 1));
    }

    // Moved to onClick()

    if (leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal == 0) {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        setTimer(originalTimerTimeInMilliSeconds);
    } else {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        setTimer(leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal);
    }

    startTimer();
}

private int getOperand1() {

    operand1 = 0;
    do {
        operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
    } while (operand1 < 1 || operand1 > 20);
    return operand1;
}

private int getOperand2() {

    operand2 = 0;
    do {
        operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
    } while (operand2 < 1 || operand2 > 20);
    return operand2;
}

private int getAnswer() {       
        if (operator == 0) {
        answer = operand1 + operand2;
        }

        else if (operator == 1) {
        answer = operand1 - operand2;
        }

        else if (operator == 2) {
        answer = operand1 * operand2;
        }

        else if (operator == 3) {
        answer = operand1 / operand2;
        }
           return answer;
        }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Could you condense it into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to show the second question after first question ? yes it can be done. Use the handler. When you click the button send a message and show the first question. After that show a handler message with delayed time to show the second question.

`mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRST_QUESTION_ID);//Fist question willbe shown immediately
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SECOND_QUESTION_ID, 2000)// second question will be shown after 1st question after 2s`

Comment: Where do I put those codes at? And will the first question still be shown when 2nd question is shown?